# Rows to Dynamic columns in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a setup in Access where some rows in a table are converted to columns...for example, lets say I have this table:

```
Team    Employee    DaysWorked
Sales    John         23
Sales    Mark         3
Sales    James        5
```

And then through the use of a query/form/something else, I would like the following display:

```
Team   John   Mark   James
Sales   23     3       5
```

This conversion of rows to columns would have to be dynamic as a team could have any number of Employees and the Employees could change etc. Could anyone please guide me on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a CrossTab query. Here's the SQL that you can use.

```
TRANSFORM SUM(YourTable.DaysWorked) AS DaysWorked
SELECT YourTable.Team
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourTable.Team
PIVOT YourTable.Employee
```

Of course the output is slightly different in that the columns are in alphabetical order.

```
Team   James  John  Mark
Sales  5      23    3
```

For more detail see [Make summary data easier to read by using a crosstab query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-select-or-crosstab-query-mdb-HP005187965.aspx) at office.microsoft.com