# Converting multiple rows into single row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that has multiple rows for a distinct CARD_ID listing different roles assigned to that CARD_ID.  I'd like to have a query that creates a single row for each distinct CARD_ID that has multiple columns listing the different roles.  See image for example of current table.  Duplicates are highlighted.

[image]

So, I'd like one row for CARD_IDs 1-10, with columns in each row for Cardholder, Reconciler, and Approver.

If a particular CARD_ID doesn't have one of those roles, I'm ok with that field being null or having some other type of indicator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rows to Dynamic columns in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523520/rows-to-dynamic-columns-in-access)

Comment: AKA [tag:pivot] queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method i conditional aggregation:

```
select card_id,
       max(iif(role = 'Reconciler', col, NULL)) as reconciler_col,
       max(iif(role = 'Approver', col, NULL)) as approver_col,
       max(iif(role = 'Cardholder', col, NULL)) as cardholder_col
from t
group by card_id;
```

`col` is a column that you want to pivot.  You can add more than one column, just by adding more `max(iif . . .)` to the `select`.

Comment: Thank you that mostly worked, except for the fact that nothing is showing up in the Reconciler column.  It's blank all the way down, even though several should have that column filled.

Comment: Nevermind that--it had to do with an extra space before Reconciler in the original table.  Thanks!